# Importing data from a csv file in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I tried to import data from a csv file. But it is not working. Can anybody help me?

My csv file:

username,password
usr1,pswd1
usr2,pswd2,
usr3,pswd3
......
.....

My CSV Data Set Config:

File name: D:\Jmeter\Data\Login.csv
Variable names: username,password
Allowed quoted data?:True
Recycle on EOF?:False
Stop thread on EOF?:True

But in the request body the username and password are not reflected

POST data:
__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24submit_btn&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=5yDYRGJAvmOFe2yRZWqpXcU%2Fjy4d3kuQN0MiJSPN%2BSjcO4%2BWHatlhSCDH%2FYSsVkXcmaeSOeM5tgjxITgfplBaZdFcWAehSjSj6pCmpSNqI0%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=rLAwRsfGRJxIUNuCrGNKSRwRWmH8KlXvFg85hbvt%2FUx9fI3qEEImGpMg%2Fi97mHb20kuESntswMVH5c%2BTkET8ludQxvA9%2Bnoz2wV2W4d%2FgcvK0rvRULKQhR4OxiVNJXQq2q3bR1cIUpYOIFbTEOyumwLlATsfrS1eAfuKZ8UEkeY%3D&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24username_txt=%24%28username%29&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24password_txt=%24%28password%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am just elaborating that how to creating\importing data from CSV

1.Create a CSV file in desired path-->`D:\Jmeter\Data\Login.csv`

Having data like this:-

```
                   usr1,pswd1
                   usr2,pswd2
                   usr3,pswd3
```

2.Add the csv data config similler to attached image
[image]

3.Use the username and password where you want like below snapshot
[image]

Hope it will work for you

Comment: I have done this. And i have a doubt. When i saw some videos related to reading a csv file, after running the script in the Response body there was a section for POST data  which shows the username and password for each request. But when i tried, this POST data section is not showing.